# How can I get AWS Batch to run more than 2 or 3 jobs at a time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-fargate, aws-batch

I'm just getting started with AWS. I have a (rather complicated) Python script which reads in some data from an S3 bucket, does some computation, and then exports some results to the same S3 bucket. I've packaged everything in a Docker container, and I'm trying to run it in parallel (say, 50 instances at a time) using AWS Batch.

I've set up a compute environment with the following parameters: 
Type: MANAGED 
Provisioning model: FARGATE 
Maximum vCPUs: 256

I then set up a job queue using that compute environment.

Next, I set up a job definition using my Docker image with the following parameters: 
vCpus: 1 
Memory: 6144

Finally, I submitted a bunch of jobs using that job definition with slightly different commands and sent them to my queue.

As I submitted the first few jobs, I saw the status of the first 2 jobs go from RUNNABLE to STARTING to RUNNING. However, the rest of them just sat there in the RUNNABLE state until the first 2 were finished.

Does anyone have any idea what the bottleneck might be to running more than 2 or 3 jobs at a time? I'm aware that there are some account limitations, but I'm not sure which one might be the bottleneck.

Comment: Fargate scales very slowly. Is there any chance for you to check with EC2 compute environment?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out there were 3 things at play here:

1. There was a service quota on my account of 5 public IP addresses, and each container was getting its own IP address so it could communicate with the S3 bucket. I made one of the subnets a private subnet and put all my containers in that subnet. I then set up a NAT gateway in a public subnet and routed all my traffic through the gateway. (More details at https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/nat-gateway-vpc-private-subnet/)
2. As Marcin pointed out, Fargate does scale slowly. I switched to using EC2, which scaled much more quickly but still stopped scaling at around 30 container instances.
3. There was a service quota on my account called "EC2 Instances / Instance Limit (All Standard (A, C, D, H, I, M, R, T, Z) instances)" which was set to 32. I reached out to AWS, and they raised the limit, so I am now able to run over 100 jobs at once.

Comment: Kevin, how did you find out these were the issue? Especially the first one (public IPs limit). I'm probably hitting the same limit but wouldn't think of it? Is there a way to check myself or did you reach out to the support?

Comment: I had previously changed the "assign public IP" setting to resolve an "unable to load container" error I was getting. When I then had the scaling problems, I wondered if the problem was caused by something I had done. Getting AWS to work how you want it to seems to just be a lot of trial and error, and it's oftentimes not made clear when you've run up against a service quota. You may have some luck with their support, though I've found them to be slow in responding.

Comment: @KevinRoche Do you know how Batch decides when it needs to spin up another EC2 instance? For example, if a long running job has a variable memory usage profile that increases toward the end, is Batch somehow able to make an intelligent decision about where to run additional jobs or will it fill up a single EC2 until there is immediate memory pressure?

Comment: @medley56 When running Docker containers on Batch, you have to specify a hard memory limit before starting the container. That amount of memory will be allocated for the job on an EC2 instance when you start running it. For example, if you have an EC2 instance with 16 GB of memory and your job requires 1 GB for most of the time but 6 GB at the end, you have to give the job 6 GB off the bat. This means that on your 16 GB EC2 instance, you can only run two jobs at a time. Batch scales up (quickly) and scales down (more slowly) the number of EC2 instances based on the number of jobs in the queue.